# React - Element reference is undefined in onLoad call

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to dynamically update my element's styles but finding that the reference to that element is `undefined` no matter what I try.

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    computeStyle(htmlElement, height) {
        if (htmlElement== null)
            return;

        htmlElement.style.height = height + "px";
    }

    render() {    
        return (
            <div
                ref={(ref) => this.htmlElement= ref}
                onLoad={() => this.computeStyle(this.htmlElement, this.props.height)}
            >
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When the `div` loads, I want to call the `computeStyle` function in order to update some styles. The real function is much more complex in its calculations.

However, when running this, the styles do not update properly. The `htmlElement` turns out to be `undefined`. Why is this?

Note: I am using React 15 and do not have access to the `React.createRef()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ref` is working totally fine! To test it, just give the `div` a `backgroundColor: 'red'` style, and an `onClick` property which calls `{() => this.computeStyle(this.htmlElement, this.props.height)}`, you will see that it works as expected. 
Now how to achieve what you're expecting is to use `componentDidMount` instead of `onLoad`!

```
    export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        this.computeStyle(this.htmlElement, this.props.height)
      }

    computeStyle(htmlElement, height) {
      if (htmlElement === null) return;

      htmlElement.style.height = height + "px";
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div
          style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
          ref={ref => (this.htmlElement = ref)}
        >
        </div>
      );
     }
   }
```